# How to install missing code page (charmap) in OS X

Tags: macos, character-encoding, osx-snow-leopard, locale, darwin

I miss a certain code page on my system (IBM-1146) and need to install it. But I can't find how. Google is very quiet about that.

I know that it is missing because iconv complains:
`iconv: conversion from IBM-1146 unsupported`

And `iconv -l` confirms that the charmap is not installed.
Some research implied that I could install it using `localedef` but I can't find the corresponding charmap file anywhere on the net.

Any help greatly appreciated.